# One-liner to find path to ROS stack or package

Tags: ros, path, ros-hydro, stack, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if there was a clean way to find the path to a given ROS stack or package from the command line on Hydro, whether it is installed or just in the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`,  i.e. what is probably used by `roscd` or `roslaunch` with the `$(find ros_stack)` arguments.

If I try to find an uninstalled ROS stack with `rospack find ros_stack`, it fails, whereas `rosstack find ros_stack` succeeds. For now I use this trick which works for both packages and stacks, whether they are installed or just present in `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`:

```
$ ros_stack_path=`roscd ros_stack && pwd && cd - &>/dev/null`
```

Is there a better one-liner for this?

I also noticed something surprising. If I try both `rospack` and `rosstack` on a metapackage (e.g. `navigation`):

```
$ rospack  find navigation             ---> fails
$ rosstack find navigation             ---> succeeds
```

Is that the expected behavior?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127821/one-liner-to-find-path-to-ros-stack-or-package/) by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 596 on 2014-02-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
rosstack find pkg_name 2>/dev/null || rospack find pkg_name
```

This can also be defined as a Bash function

```
rosstack_pack(){
  rosstack $@ 2>/dev/null || rospack $@
}
```

and used like

```
rosstack_pack find pkg_name
```

Further magic would be required for autocompletion to work.

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2014-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-02-11**:
I guess this is the most direct way to go. Thanks!